Longhorn Replicas Not Allocating on Worker Node 3
I've installed Longhorn on my Kubernetes cluster and configured specific settings, such as the default data path, over-provisioning (50% of the available space, with each node having 200GB, so 100GB is allocated), auto replica balancing, and more.
However, when I check the Longhorn UI, I notice that there are no replicas on Worker Node 3. Instead, only the "used" space is shown. After investigating, I found that containerd is occupying most of the available space.
My question is: Is the lack of space on Worker Node 3 the reason why it cannot allocate any replicas, or could there be another underlying issue causing this problem?


Since this post is not about programming, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It may be on-topic on [sf] or DevOps.
